# How can I check `elasticsearch is down` condition in my service?

Tags: spring, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch, spring-actuator

I have some service. I need return data from elastic search if it available or return from DB:

```
@Service
class DefaulUserService implements UserService {

    private final DbDao dbDao;
    private final ElasticsearchDao elasticsearchDao;

    DefaultDoctorService(DbDao dbDao, ElasticsearchDao elasticsearchDao) {
        this.dbDao= dbDao;
        this.elasticsearchDao= elasticsearchDao;
    }

    @Override
    public List<User> findAll() {
       if(elasticsearch is down){
             return dbDao.findAll();
        } else {
             return elasticsearchDao.findAll();
       }
    }
}
```

How can I check the `elasticsearch is down` condition in my service?

Comment: what is `ElasticsearchDao`?

Comment: @ P.J.Meisch class which contains `ElasticsearchOperations` or `ElasticsearchRepository` and delegates operations with Elasticsearch to them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's truly down, `elasticsearchDao.findAll();` should surely raise an exception, right?

```java
@Service
class DefaultUserService implements UserService {

    private final DbDao dbDao;
    private final ElasticsearchDao elasticsearchDao;

    DefaultDoctorService(DbDao dbDao, ElasticsearchDao elasticsearchDao) {
        this.dbDao= dbDao;
        this.elasticsearchDao= elasticsearchDao;
    }

    @Override
    public List<User> findAll() {
        try {
            return elasticsearchDao.findAll();
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            return dbDao.findAll();
        }
    }
}
```

Obviously you'd have to pick a more appropriate type of exception to catch.

Comment: It last way to do it. Of course, I can do it, but it looks quite crooked

Comment: @PavelPetrashov You can also make use of https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/master/java-rest-high-cluster-health.html API and check `ClusterHealthStatus status = response.getStatus(); `. But it might be expensive to check cluster state on each and every request, that's why I proposed just to catch ES exception to avoid redundant HTTP calls.

Comment: I'd suggest the same to prevent an additional call to ES

Comment: Yes, I realized that this approach will kill 2 problems. Might be a situation when I check elasticsearch health and get an exception anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use the [ES cluster health API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cluster-health.html) and check it. it will not only check the uptime of ES, but the same API can be used to get the health status of only specified data streams and indices.

**Few important statuses**

1. RED:- One or more primary shard missing.
2. Yeloow:- One or more Replica shard missing.
3. Green:- Everything fine :)

Comment: Yes, but my question was about java API. I use spring data elastic search. I can call the HTTP method with health requests, but I am looking for something easier, like the library method.  `elasticsearchOperations.health();`